# Typescript compilation with Gulp empty folder and namespace errors

Tags: typescript, gulp

I have a problem with Gulp when I want to compile Typescript in an ASPNET project :

```
gulp.task('compileTs', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src([paths.source + paths.scripts + '**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(ts());
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});
```

It returns errors like :

```
scripts\app.d.ts(68,198): error TS2503: Cannot find namespace 'Data'.
scripts\app.d.ts(69,78): error TS2305: Module 'xxx' has no exported member 'Data'.
...
```

And there is nothing in my dest folder.

I try with a compilation options (in a tsconfig.json) :

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "ES5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": true,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "noExternalResolve": true,
        "removeComments": true,
        "outFile": "rexApp.js",
        "sourceMap": true,
    },
    "exclude": [
        "**/*.d.ts",
        "node_modules",
        "typings/**/*"
    ]
}
var tsProject = ts.createProject('tsconfig.json', {
    typescript: require('typescript')
});
gulp.task('tscompile', function () {
    var tsResult = gulp.src([paths.source + paths.scripts + '**/*.ts'])
    .pipe(ts(tsProject));
    return tsResult.js.pipe(gulp.dest(paths.dest));
});
```

I have no error but nothing in my dest folder again.

What did I missed?

Thank's in advance !

Comment: You are most probably missing some type definitions files ( d.ts ) can you paste your app.d.ts ( or at least the lines 68, 69 )?

Comment: thanks! all these errors come when the xxx.Data is used. 
The file with the declaration of Data "declare module xxx.Data { ...}" is in another folder, in Models/xxxData.d.ts. which has a reference path "<reference path="../../scripts/typings/jaydata/jaydata.d.ts" />"

Comment: No error if I change the source path by " paths.source + '**/*.ts' " (I removed the paths to the script folder, so I take all the typescript file), but still nothing in my destination folder.